Unresolved external symbol: static function declared in class defined in cpp file
my code looks like this:
//Renderer.h file
#pragma once

class Renderer {
public:
static int Test();
};

//Renderer.cpp file
#include "../Header/Renderer.h"
#include <iostream>

int Renderer::Test() {
    std::cout << "This is a test" << std::endl;
    return 1
}


//main.cpp file
#include "Renderer/Header/Renderer.h"
int main()
{
    Renderer::Test();
}

Whenever I try to run this code, I get an unresolved external symbol error. I tried creating a different file with a dummy class, had the same exact code and this one worked just fine without any errors.
I really don't get what I did wrong.

Ok, so I made a new header and cpp file and copied the respecting content from Renderer.h and Renderer.cpp over to the new files, deleted the original files and renamed the new files to the same as the old files, and now it works. The issue seemed to be with visual studio.
